# Router - How to set up User Portal Web page?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm really not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but here it goes (suggestions if this isn't the correct place):

I was wondering if it was possible to to do the following with my router:

> Random user connects to wireless
>
> User then opens a browser and proceeds to search
>
> Before the user is able to continue to their page they are presented with my custom web page with my custom content.
>
> User clicks next on the web page and searching continues as normal.

My current router: TP-LINK TD-W8980

If anyone has any suggestions or maybe a correct place to post this I'd be really grateful.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Wi-Fi industry terminology this is called a "**captive portal**". If you search for that term, you can learn a lot more.

Most home Wi-Fi routers' factory firmware doesn't support captive portal features. It's possible that aftermarket (often open source) firmware distros like DD-WRT, OpenWrt, Tomato, etc. might, if you can find one that supports your model of router.

Most enterprise-class or public-access-class Wi-Fi gear support captive portal in the factory firmware.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Really helpful. I'm reading up on it on wikipedia now. I did Google: "guest user router web portal" but as you can guess, It didn't really get me that far :P. I'm a software developer all of this networking and hardware is above me :/

Answer (score 1):

if your router supports "captive portal" natively then you can do that, if not

you have to update your router's firmware to one 3rd party which provides the service
like this

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

goto this site and type your modem model no. if you can find the list download and update.
then you will be able to achieve what you want. and not only this but also several open source 3rd parties also available

Comment: Thanks :) I really wish I could get dd-wrt but it seems I'm not able to I don't think :c